# What are the phrases for silly choices

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, idiom-request

What are the phrases for "giving up something big for something small", emphasizing that it is not a smart move? E.g., in one TV episode, the main character thinks gathering golf balls from ponds in a golf court is a lucrative business, so he gives up his normal job to do so.

**EDIT:** @Merk, **the example** illustrates what I'm asking for. The "giving up something big" is not, it is somewhat directly translated from Chinese idiom, *"throw away a melon to pick up a sesame"*, **emphasizing silly choices**. I think a close phrase in English is, *"give up a dollar for a dime"*, if there is such a saying at all.

Comment: The example you give, which does not seem to have much to do with 'giving up something big', is a case of 'making a wrong/bad bet.'  Sounds like he also 'bet the farm.'

Comment: Inspired by an English proverb, "Venture a great fish to catch a small one." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"Trading down" could work.  For example, you could *trade down* from living in a mansion to living in an apartment.  It doesn't have to be strictly applied to a single barter transaction — selling the mansion and buying the apartment in two independent transactions could still be considered *trading down*.

Note that you can only use *trading down* when giving up something big that you already have.  If you give up a big opportunity in favor of an inferior option, that's not *trading down*.  Also, it doesn't have a strong sense of stupidity built in, which you seem to be looking for in your phrase request.

Answer (score 0):

"Penny-wise and pound foolish".

Edited to add: I think I once heard someone say of someone else, "He'll trade two dimes for a nickel", but I don't know it's caught on as an idiom.

Comment: "Penny-wise and pound foolish" is not quite right — it has more to do with false economies.

Comment: This is really close, but I think 200_success is right. When I think of Penny-wise and pound foolish, I think for example of someone who will, say, buy a used item in poor repair, then spend more than the item is worth getting it into working condition. There is a close phrase, though "Spend a pound to earn a penny" that might be a bit closer to the meaning? It is sometimes used as the moral of the Aesop's story about the dog who loses his bone in the river.